# Change the value of CSS style when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all I want to explain what I want to do, I want to change the value of a certain CSS style which is the `border-bottom-color` when scrolled. But the problem is, it's not working while the other style is working `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a`. Can someone explain me why it's not working? I'm new to HTML and CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 36) {
      $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a").css("color", "white"); //Working
      $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover").css("border-bottom-color", "white");
    } else {
      $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a").css("color", "black"); //Working
      $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover").css("border-bottom-color", "rgb(2,1,131)");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: rgb(2, 1, 131);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(2, 1, 131);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="36">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.serbizcooperative.com/"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" width="400px"></a>
      <img src="img/gear.png" class="gear" width="15px">
      <img src="img/lightning.png" class="lightning" width="25px">
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HR Express</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you cannot use :hover css property as script selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use CSS over jquery like below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a").mouseover(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 36) {
      $(this).css("color", "red"); //Working
      $(this).css("border-bottom-color", "rgb(2, 1, 131)");
    } else {
      $(this).css("color", "black"); //Working
      $(this).css("border-bottom-color", "rgb(2,1,131)");
    }
  });
  
  $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a").mouseleave(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 36) {
      $(this).css("color", "black"); 
      $(this).css("border-bottom-color", "transparent");
    } else {
      $(this).css("color", "black");
      $(this).css("border-bottom-color", "transparent");
    }
  });
  
})
```

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: rgb(2, 1, 131);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(2, 1, 131);
}

body {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="36">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.serbizcooperative.com/"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" width="400px"></a>
      <img src="img/gear.png" class="gear" width="15px">
      <img src="img/lightning.png" class="lightning" width="25px">
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HR Express</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The problem is, it's in the transition. The color never fade away it stays white the transition never happen the border bottom color stays.

Comment: @nethkennnnn Still I didn't get what you are looking for. Can please explain so if I can help

Comment: Take a look at my css, it has a transition, the border bottom color will change from `transparent` to `rgb(2, 1, 131)` when hover and if the mouse leave it will become transparent again. So my problem now is i want to change the transition color when scrolled I want it to become from `transparent` to `white` when scrolled. Sorry for my explanation im not fluent in english.

Comment: @nethkennnnn okay got it.. updated code with `mouseover` and `mouseleave` function. so on mouse leave reset css as original

Comment: Thankyou bro! It worked. Can you recommend a site to read more about javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your script like this

```
var wrap = $("#wrap");

wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {

  if (this.scrollTop > 147) {
      // change color here
  } else {
      // change color here
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define a separate style for both cases, i.e. `.navbar-menuitem` and `.navbar-menuitem-scrolled` or something similar. Then use Javascript to add or remove the class from the item you are targeting.

What you are trying to do in jQuery above is target the CSS of a possible state of the element. jQuery does not have access to that unless the element is already in the hover state. jQuery is used to manipulate the elements in their present state, not their stylesheets, though it does have access to the currently applied styles.

Use the `.addClass()` and .`removeClass()` methods to solve your problem. Remember to use `.hasClass()` so you do not add the class a billion times when scrolling up and down the page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use :hover css on script selector. You are suppose to use jquery `hover()` or `mouseover()` to achieve this. Something like below

```
$('.navbar-nav>li>a').hover(function(){
    if(scroll>36){
       //change border-color
    }
    else{
      //change border-color
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is, it's in the transition. The color never fade away it stays white the transition never happen the border bottom color stays.

Comment: So you mean that, issue is about transition css only?

Comment: Take a look at my css, it has a transition, the border bottom color will change from transparent to rgb(2, 1, 131) when hover and if the mouse leave it will become transparent again. So my problem now is i want to change the transition color when scrolled I want it to become from transparent to white when scrolled. Sorry for my explanation im not fluent in english.